# "The maximum total size of all input parameters is 5242880 bytes." Error message when using BigQuery remote function

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, bigquery-udf

When calling a remote function on BigQuery, I get the following error `The maximum total size of all input parameters is 5242880 bytes.`. This error is undocumented (or my Googling ability is lacking). It is even more unexpected as the query that pop this error is as simple as it gets:

```
SELECT
  `remote_function`( payload ) AS results
FROM
  `source_table`
```

The error is definitely on BQ's side, as no error is observed on the cloud-function called.

How to proceed on such issue, I'm guessing that I'm hitting some kind of limit related to remote functions, but which one?

[image: Screenshot with the query and the error]

Comment: This limit is documented here. `Maximum input size 5 MB (The maximum total size of all input arguments from a single row is 5 MB.)` https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#remote_function_limits

Comment: Good catch Marton!

Comment: Indeed, I did not read well the documentation. @Pentium10 you may want to put your response in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#remote_function_limits).

Maximum input size 5 MB (The maximum total size of all input arguments from a single row is 5 MB.)